# New columns in Ext.grid.property.Grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

Is there a way to add a new columns in [Ext.grid.property.Grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid)? By default there is Name and Value and I want to add few columns such as New Value and [xtype: 'actioncolumn'](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action) with handlers to approve new value or not. And you know how to rename default columns? I found nothing in official docs about that.

Thank you.

Comment: The last time I asked on sencha forum, which was in late 2013/early 2014, I was told that this isn't supported by ExtJS framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add new columns to `Ext.grid.property.Grid` or rename its columns out of the box.

You can rename columns with something like:

```
listeners : {
    beforerender : function() {
        var cols = this.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();
        cols[0].setText("Property");
        cols[1].setText("Data");
    }
}
```

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15q7)

I guess you also can overrite `Ext.grid.property.Grid` so you can add new columns, but I guess its easier to just work with `Ext.grid.Panel`.